# how to resolve Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to build cipher: Illegal key size using aws s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am trying for encryption and decryption using amazon aws. I got exception like

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to build cipher: Illegal key size
    Make sure you have the JCE unlimited strength policy files installed and configured for your JVM
        at  com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.ContentCryptoScheme.createCipherLite(ContentCryptoScheme.java:190)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.ContentCryptoMaterial.wrap(ContentCryptoMaterial.java:823)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.S3CryptoModuleBase.buildContentCryptoMaterial(S3CryptoModuleBase.java:535)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.S3CryptoModuleBase.newContentCryptoMaterial(S3CryptoModuleBase.java:483)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.S3CryptoModuleBase.createContentCryptoMaterial(S3CryptoModuleBase.java:449)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.S3CryptoModuleBase.putObjectUsingMetadata(S3CryptoModuleBase.java:165)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.S3CryptoModuleBase.putObjectSecurely(S3CryptoModuleBase.java:159)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.CryptoModuleDispatcher.putObjectSecurely(CryptoModuleDispatcher.java:107)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3EncryptionClient.putObject(AmazonS3EncryptionClient.java:485)
        at testKMSkeyUploadObject.main(testKMSkeyUploadObject.java:91)
    Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1039)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.crypto.ContentCryptoScheme.createCipherLite(ContentCryptoScheme.java:187)
        ... 9 more

please help me.
```

when I was trying to put object for doing encryption using AmazonS3EncryptionClient I am getting exception. How to resolve this error.

```
AmazonS3EncryptionClient s3 = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(credentials,materialProvider);

PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
                            bucket, kms_cmk_id, new ByteArrayInputStream(plaintext), metadata);

ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                    objectMetadata.setSSEAlgorithm(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);   

putRequest.setMetadata(objectMetadata);
System.out.println(putRequest.getKey());
s3.putObject(putRequest); //getting exception here
```

Comment: Please align your code properly. It is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by creating encryption key in IAM Management Console. I used that encryption key when I was encrypting.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the problem is with key size and IMO Amazon has hard coded it somewhere in their code. The solution may be to go for unlimited strength file which you can download from:

[Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)

[Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

[Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)

Install the file in `${java.home}/jre/lib/security/`.

Comment: I done all things. Now I am getting exception like                                                Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 428E4EC19BC3820D),

Comment: Is there any reason mentioned for `Access Denied`?

Comment: I provided all access credentials correctly. I resolved that error by creating encryption key in IAM Users. Now I am getting exception like    Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null. how to resolve this exception?